# Camel context and exception separation

Tags: xml, apache-camel, spring-camel

I have separated the camel xml files like

1. FileA.xml

```
<routeContext id="routeA" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <route id="...">
        <from uri="..."/>
            <to uri="..."/>
    </route>
</routeContext>
```

2. FileB.xml

```
<routeContext id="routeB" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <route id="...">
        <from uri="..."/>
            <to uri="..."/>
    </route>
</routeContext>
```

3. Core.xml

```
<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring" >
    <routeContextRef ref="routeA"/>
    <routeContextRef ref="routeB" />
</camelContext>
```

This setup works fine.

Now I want to add onException to a different xml file and need to import that in Core.xml because we need to handle a lot of different Exceptions.

```
<onException>
    <exception>org.apache.camel.ExpressionEvaluationException</exception>
    <handled>
        <constant>true</constant>
    </handled>
    <to uri="..."/>
</onException>
```

The problem is `<onException>` can be only added inside `<camelContext>`  So I can't able to separate the exception.xml files from core.xml.

1. Is there a way to do like this (importing the exception.xml file into core.xml file) ?
2. Can I have multiple camel context file and add/import one context into another ?

kindly help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Camel 2.x it was possible to have multiple Camel Contexts in one application. With Camel 3.x this was removed and [**only 1 Camel Context is supported**](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/camel-3-migration-guide.html#_multiple_camelcontexts_per_application_not_supported).

Therefore, even if it would work in Camel 2.x to have multiple `camelContext` XML files (I don't know if it does work), it is at least not future proof. So you should stick with 1 `camelContext` XML that imports the `routeContext`s.

Now the error handlers and exception clauses. In Camel they can have either global scope or route scope.

- if they are route scoped, the are in the corresponding `routeContext`s anyway. So no problem here
- if they are global scoped they must be in the single `camelContext` file as far as I know

However, what you are free to do is to put all the error stuff in separate XML file(s) and **merge them somehow during your build**. For example with a Maven plugin or something similar.

Like this you have a **clean separation in your code** and **Camel has a single `camelContext` file** with all in it except the separate `routeContext`s. So hopefully both of you, you and the Camel get happy :-)